# Scaling ImageView to device width

Tags: android, layout, imageview

In my Android App I have a Activity which show images which have following size `244 x 330`.
I want to show those images in full device width.

My layout file looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <LinearLayout 
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="fill_parent"
      android:orientation="vertical">

            <ImageView android:id="@+id/news_image" 
                android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_marginLeft="18dip"
                android:layout_marginRight="18dip"
                android:background="#aaaaaa" />


    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

I tried to set the ScaleType of the ImageView but there is no ScalingType which scales the ImageView proportional.
How can I scale the image proportionally to fit the whole screen in landscape mode AND portrait mode?

Basically what I want is something like ScaleType.CENTER_CORP but which also sets the proportional height for the image so I can see all of it and not just a part of the image.

**Edit cause I know I'm confusing you with my "weird" questing.**

I want to show it to you with a image.
This is what I get at the moment with my layout. I want to fill the whole grey area by scaling the image as big as needed. How can I accomplish that?

[image]

When I set the `ScaleType` to `CENTER_CROP` I get this

[image]

but this is not what I want cause you are not seeing the whole image just a part from the center.

And this is what I want it to be:

[image]

I hope this helps you to understand what I'm trying to accomplish.
Anyone knows how to do that?

**Edit 2:**

It might look weird and little confusing that I'm trying to display a image which is bigger in the height than the screen size but since I'm using a `ScrollView` in my example layout this should be ok and the user could scroll if he want to see the not displayed area.

Hope this helps to understand what I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

I tried really every `ScaleType` in my `ImageView` with `fill_parent` and `wrap_content` but no of them worked. I also tried everything what I found on Google but nothing worked for me either so came up with something on my own.

It was clear that the ImageView is not scaling my image like I wanted to be scaled so I had to scale it on my own. After scaling the bitmap I would set the new Bitmap as the image source to the ImageView. This works pretty good and looks very good on the G1 and on the Motorola Milestone 2.

And here is all pieces of my code

Layout:

```
<ScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <LinearLayout 
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="fill_parent"
      android:id="@+id/news_wrapper">

            <ImageView android:id="@+id/news_image" 
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_marginLeft="18dip"
                android:layout_marginRight="18dip"
                android:background="#aaaaaa" />

    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Activity

```
public class ScalingImages extends Activity {

    private ImageView imageView;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.test_margin);

        this.imageView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.news_image);

        // The image is coming from resource folder but it could also 
        // load from the internet or whatever
        Drawable drawable = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.img);
        Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable)drawable).getBitmap();

        // Get scaling factor to fit the max possible width of the ImageView
        float scalingFactor = this.getBitmapScalingFactor(bitmap);

        // Create a new bitmap with the scaling factor
        Bitmap newBitmap = Util.ScaleBitmap(bitmap, scalingFactor);

        // Set the bitmap as the ImageView source
        this.imageView.setImageBitmap(newBitmap);
    }

    private float getBitmapScalingFactor(Bitmap bm) {
        // Get display width from device
        int displayWidth = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getWidth();

        // Get margin to use it for calculating to max width of the ImageView
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = 
            (LinearLayout.LayoutParams)this.imageView.getLayoutParams();
        int leftMargin = layoutParams.leftMargin;
        int rightMargin = layoutParams.rightMargin;

        // Calculate the max width of the imageView
        int imageViewWidth = displayWidth - (leftMargin + rightMargin);

        // Calculate scaling factor and return it
        return ( (float) imageViewWidth / (float) bm.getWidth() );
    }
}
```

Util class

```
public class Util {

    public static Bitmap ScaleBitmap(Bitmap bm, float scalingFactor) {
        int scaleHeight = (int) (bm.getHeight() * scalingFactor);
        int scaleWidth = (int) (bm.getWidth() * scalingFactor);

        return Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bm, scaleWidth, scaleHeight, true);
    }

}
```

If there is an better or more accurate way to accomplish the same scaling **please let me know** because I can't believe that such a trivial thing is so hard to accomplish.

I'm really hoping to see a better way to do this.

Thank you for reading.

Comment: Thnx for sharing. There should be a scaling factor to do this.

Comment: Thank you so much - I can't believe there isn't an easier way to do this!

Comment: I also wasted tons of time trying to use settings in the xml.  Thanks for posting your own solution.

Comment: getWidth() is now deprecated, so I use this instead... `Point size = new Point();
        getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getSize(size);
        int displayWidth = size.x;`

Answer (score 20):

the easiest way is to add android:adjustViewBounds="true" to the ImageView and set the scale type to "fitCenter"

Comment: Simple requirement with a simple solution - and it worked fine for me. (This should be the correct answer!)

Comment: This solution is perfect

Answer (score 4):

Slightly confused on what you're looking for, exactly. If you're scaling to fit the screen, you have three options, two of which are viable if you're keeping proportions. You can use ScaleType fitCenter, which will make the image fit within the bounds proportionally, or you can use centerCrop (which you said you tried), which will stretch the shortest side of the image to fit the container (meaning some will get cropped off on the longer dimension). You can't have it stretch to fit the width AND height without either cropping, or stretching disproportionately.

**EDIT**: Okay, I think I get your point now. First, I'd set your LinearLayout to wrap_content for the height. Second, in code, here's one way you can do it that I can think of. There's probably also another way you could do it by first getting the screen dimensions, and then doing `createScaledBitmap` with the new dimensions, and then setting the background resource.

```
final ImageView newsImage = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.news_image);

//get details on resolution from the display
DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);

//going to set what happens as the layout happens
newsImage.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(
    new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {

        public void onGlobalLayout() {
            int oldHeight, oldWidth, newHeight, newWidth;

            //we want the new width to be as wide as the screen
            newWidth = metrics.widthPixels;

            oldHeight = newsImage.getDrawable().getIntrinsicHeight();
            oldWidth = newsImage.getDrawable().getIntrinsicWidth();

            //keeping the aspect ratio, the new height should be w1/h1 = w2/h2
            newHeight = Math.floor((oldHeight * newWidth) / oldWidth);
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = 
                (LinearLayout.LayoutParams)newsImage.getLayoutParams();
            params.height = newHeight;
            params.width = newWidth;
            newsImage.setLayoutParams(params);
            newsImage.setScaleType(ScaleType.CENTER);
            newsImage.invalidate();
            newsImage.getViewTreeObserver().removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried that but `ScaleType.CENTER_CROP`did cut the height. Can you provide a sample? I will try it again (maybe I made somewhere a mistake) and post my results.

Comment: You HAVE to cut the height if you want to make it fit the width. To do what you're wanting, you'd use the fitXY scaling type, but it will scale disproportionately. There's not any other way to do this.

Comment: But I don't want to fit the image to the height of the screen. If the image is bigger than the display height the user can scroll the image since I use a ScrollView in my example. What I want is fit width but don't cut height and make it scrollable if height is bigger than display height. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4):

I googled everywhere and could not find a solution.
Here is what I did, that worked for me and with a scroll view.

XML file:

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/manga_page_image"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter" />
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: Confirmed ! It worked for me too and it's much easier than scaling the  image via code

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried setting it programmatically via `ImageView.setScaleType()`?

`setAdjustViewBounds( false )` might help as well.

Edit: sorry, I mis-read the question. Regardless, `setAdjustViewBounds()` *still* might help. Never used it though.

Comment: I just tried `setAdjustViewBounds` but it didn't help. Any other suggestions? Maybe my edit is making my goal better to understand.

Answer (score 2):

> I want to show those images in full
>   device width.

This is simple.   You just have the wrong margin settings.  Remove these lines and your image will show in full device width:

```
android:layout_marginLeft="18dip"
android:layout_marginRight="18dip"
```

Comment: This seems strange but actually I would like to have these margins otherwise it will like so "glued" to the screen. Unless those 18 dip left and right I would like to use the entire screen size.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see the images anymore and the question is old but just in case someone else finds this and has the same problem. Wouldn't it be better to just get `float screenWidth = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels` and set the ImageView LayoutParamters programmatically to  scale the image to `screenWidth`. Just an idea !!

Answer (score 1):

manage to achieve what I wanted, which hopefully is the same as your aim:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.pgviewer);

    ImageView PgContainer = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);

    String Page = String.valueOf(getIntent().getExtras().getInt("Page"));
    try {
        PgContainer.setImageBitmap(getBitmapFromAsset(Page));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    PgContainer.setScaleType(ScaleType.FIT_CENTER);
    PgContainer.scrollTo(0, 0);
    PgContainer.setScrollBarStyle(0);
}
```

then to scale the bitmap:

```
private Bitmap getBitmapFromAsset(String strName) throws IOException
{
    AssetManager assetManager = getAssets();
    InputStream istr = assetManager.open(strName+".png");
    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(istr);

    float screenWidth = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels;
    int ih=bitmap.getHeight();
    int iw=bitmap.getWidth();
    float scalefactor = screenWidth/iw;
    //w = 480, h=~
    //int newh = bitmap.getHeight()/bitmap.getWidth();
    return android.graphics.Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, (int)(iw*scalefactor), (int)(ih*scalefactor), true);
    //return bitmap;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One of the ways to do it is by setting android:adjustViewBounds="true" to the ImageView and set the scale type to "fitCenter" in the xml file.
This should work as expected. 
You can also do this programatically by setting ImageView.adjustViewBounds(true) and ImageView.setScaleType(ScaleType.FIT_CENTER).