# Load images in android without cropping from server?

Tags: android, android-imageview, android-image

I am working on an app which has lot of images loading .There are images of people like facebook which may take 30 % height of screen size and full width .

Wrap content in Imageview does not show full image width . If I set scale type in imageview to fitxy then images get stretched and centercrop does not solve the issue . I want to the image from server without cropping , something like facebooks posts . ANy ideas on how to do this ?

Comment: I am fine with this: `<ImageView android:id="@+id/one" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" android:adjustViewBounds="true" android:scaleType="centerCrop"  />`

Answer (score 0):

You can set the ImageView's `android:adjustViewBounds` attribute to `true` if you want it to resize itself automatically to preserve an image's shape. You can also specify a maximum width and height using `android:maxHeight` and `android:maxWidth`. With a combination of those three, you can probably display your image without cropping and stretching, and confined to an area of the screen that's adequate for your UI.

Comment: Hmmm does not work still image is not scaled to device full width .The following is the solution  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4877694/scaling-imageview-to-device-width   but i have so many bit maps and may be because of scale factor i get out of memory exception .