# Stretch image in ImageView

Tags: android, imageview

I have an ImageView that has its height and width set to "fill_parent" with a Relative Layout that has the same values set.Set Image scaleType="fitXY"

Here The XML layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">


<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:src="@drawable/background_image" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

Fits the width and height but the image is stretched.

Comment: Very good solution here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4886871/1617737

Comment: possible duplicate of [Scaling ImageView to device width](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4877694/scaling-imageview-to-device-width)

Comment: Use **android:adjustViewBounds="true"** along with **android:scaleType="fitCenter"**

Answer (score 23, accepted):

That's what **`fitXY`** is supposed to do. You can try with **`centerInside`** if you don't want to crop your image, or **`centerCrop`** if you want to fill all the space (and cropping your image).

[Here](http://etcodehome.blogspot.it/2011/05/android-imageview-scaletype-samples.html) is a nice list with examples to understand better all the `scaleTypes`.

Answer (score 19):

These two properties solved issue for me:

```
android:scaleType="fitXY"
android:adjustViewBounds="true"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
package utils;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.widget.ImageView;

/**
 * Created by Navneet Boghani on 7/7/16.
 */
public class ProportionalImageView extends ImageView {

    public ProportionalImageView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public ProportionalImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public ProportionalImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        Drawable d = getDrawable();
        if (d != null) {
         //   int w = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);
          //  int h = w * d.getIntrinsicHeight() / d.getIntrinsicWidth();
            int h = MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec);
            int w = h * d.getIntrinsicWidth() / d.getIntrinsicHeight();
            setMeasuredDimension(w, h);
        }
        else super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
    }
}
```

Comment: a little explination??

Answer (score 0):

That is what fitXY will do. It will not respect the aspect ratio of the image and fill the image to your imageview without maintaining the original aspect ratio of the image. If you want to match size of your image to your view ,you can scale your image yourself or  you can look glide library to do that for you . Glide is a very useful library when it comes to image in android