# How can I make images fit every device on android application

Tags: android

I am inserting buttons and images which should touch the borders horizontally of the android device's width, but they are not a result there is little space left on both the sides of the button and images. And when I test the app on a larger dimension device the images and button appear pretty small comparatively. What should I do?

Comment: Show your code and snapshot.

Comment: @PiyushGupta here is the code:

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/one_one"
        android:textSize="25sp" />

</LinearLayout>

Answer (score 0):

These links will help you to create application for multiple screens :

http://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screensizes.html

http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

These are android's official documents on implementing support for multiple screen sizes.

```
<supports-screens android:smallScreens="true" 
          android:normalScreens="true" 
          android:largeScreens="true"
          android:xlargeScreens="true"
          android:anyDensity="true" />
```

Add this to your manifest file of your application.

Answer (score 0):

> there is little space left on both the sides of the button and images

Try changing the margin and padding of your UI components.

> And when I test the app on a larger dimension device the images and
>   button appear pretty small comparatively.

[Android documentation](http://developer.android.com/design/style/iconography.html) provides pretty detailed information on what size image should be used for various screen sizes. You might want to read that.

Answer (score 0):

In your XML file you can use `android:scaleType`. See documentation for [scaleType](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.ScaleType.html).

scaleType is a bit difficult to understand with the provided description unless you use each scale type and see its effects for yourself.

Programmatically you can do something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4886871/2348704) but it would very much depend on your particular use case requirement.