# Stretch to fill ImageView with rotated image

Tags: android, imageview

I want it to fill the ImageView with my rotated image.
Here's my ImageView code:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imgResult"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:rotation="90"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:src="@drawable/img_ex" />

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
    style="?android:attr/buttonBarStyle"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btCancelar"
        style="?android:attr/buttonBarButtonStyle"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Cancelar"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        />

    <View
        android:layout_width="1dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#fff" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btSalvar"
        style="?android:attr/buttonBarButtonStyle"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Salvar"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        />
</LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

In the image you can see in the blueprint the imageview size. 
[image: Screen design]

I don't mind stretching the image, I just want to fill the ImageView component

PS: I already tried this solution [Scaling ImageView to device width](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4877694/scaling-imageview-to-device-width/4886871#4886871)

Comment: @AkashPal don't work. I still get the white border around the image

Comment: @AkashPal not working either

Comment: What happens if you get rid of the weight and make the ImageView match the parent width and height?

Comment: adjustViewBounds are unnecessary for fitXY

Comment: could you please post your image, so we can check

Comment: @ruben I'm getting a bitmap from the camera, so could be any image.

Comment: @WadeWilson same problem, still don't stretch the image to fill everything

Comment: What about doing what I previously say, but remove "fitXY"?

Comment: @WadeWilson same problem

Comment: Can you post the full layout file

Comment: @WadeWilson done

Comment: The layout code you posted isn't valid. There are missing closing element tags as well as constraints on all necessary elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution was rotating the bitmap in my activity before showing it. Then it worked

```
fun rotateBitmap(source: Bitmap, angle: Float): Bitmap {
    val matrix = Matrix()
    matrix.postRotate(angle)
    return Bitmap.createBitmap(source, 0, 0, source.width, source.height, matrix, true)
}
```